# JavaScript object has no method exception

Tags: javascript, oop, methods, titanium, prototype

I have the following object defined with an included method:

```
function MaxHullSpeedCalculator(lwl) {
    this.lwl = lwl;
}

MaxHullSpeedCalculator.prototype.calculate = function() {
    var mhs = 1.34 * Math.sqrt(this.lwl);
    return mhs.toFixed(2);
};
```

However, when I try to make a call to calculate:

```
 var mhsc = new MaxHullSpeedCalculator(Ti.App.lwlBox.value);
 mhsText.setText('Hull speed: ' + mhsc.calculate()); //throws error
```

I get the following error:

```
Exception occurred at outputWindow.js:51: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<MaxHullSpeedCalculator> has no method 'calculate'
```

Does anyone know what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure?? It looks fine..

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6rhVe/ I just copy pasted your code here minor changes to make it work..

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my problem. I had to put my call to the method AFTER defining it. Previously I had my call to my method before defining it.